# EaselJS with 200+ vector shapes : performance and aesthetics

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs

I'm having a huge perf issue when using EaselJS *vs* Canvas native method : 2.2 s vs 0.01 s (although EaselJS do map canvas native methods...).

I wrote a canvas app which draws a tree*. In order to animate the growth af the tree, it seems cleaner and handier to tween an EaselJS *graphics* object than writing a custom drawing function.
*(actually it'll look more like a virginia creeper)

1) I must have done something wrong, as the perf with EaselJS are awfull.

The significant piece of the code :

```
var g=new createjs.Graphics();
g.bs(branchTexture);
for (var i=0; i < arbre.length; i++) {
    var step=arbre[i];
    for (var t=0; t < step.length; t++){
        var d=step[t];
        var c=d[5];
        var s=new createjs.Shape(g);
        s.graphics.setStrokeStyle(7*(Math.pow(.65,d[7]-1)),'round').mt(c[0],c[1]).qt(c[2],c[3],c[4],c[5]);
        }
        mainStage.addChild(s);
    }
}
mainStage.update();
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing the comparison :
http://jsfiddle.net/xxsL683x/29/

I tried removing texture, simplifying *moveTo()* operations, but the result si still very slow. Caching doesn't apply, as it's the first rendering pass.
What have I done wrong ?

2) Additionally, I need to find a way to orient the filling pattern in the direction of the growth, so I think i'll get rid of the vector shapes and interpolate some bitmap between two "growth states". If anyone has a better idea, i would be glad to read it.

(But it would be nice to have an answer to the first question though, it's probably not the last time I'll be attempting to tween complex objects.)

3) Another reason for getting rid of EaselJS is that the antialiasing doesn't apply. Why ? Also has to be investigated...

Hope this question will help others to avoid some errors, if I've done some, or at least lead to a better understanding of the way easeljs handles vector shapes.

PS : The tree do have leaves ;)... but I pulled them out for obvious clarity reasons.

Comment: EaselJS creates smart objects which require a fairly large overhead to track and manage. Alternatively, native canvas does not manage any of its drawings at all. Native canvas draws pixels on the canvas without even remembering where it drew the pixels (==fire and forget). The time difference you're experiencing is likely due to the time it takes EaselJS to manage your 200+ smart objects.

Comment: @markE - EaselJS does have some overhead for object management (it's a given in any display list), but it's generally fairly minimal vs the cost to actually render the pixels in the browser. This is a logic issue, as explained by derz below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've update your Fiddle, it's now much faster. The problem is that you're creating a new Shape in each loop, which is pretty slow.

```
 for (var t=0; t < step.length; t++){
    // loop
    g.setStrokeStyle(7*(Math.pow(.65,d[7]-1)),'round').mt(c[0],c[1]).qt(c[2],c[3],c[4],c[5]);
  }

  // then just create a Shape after all your graphic commands are built 
  var s = new createjs.Shape(g);
  mainStage.addChild(s);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xxsL683x/31/

Comment: Creator of EaselJS here: this is the correct answer. Currently you are creating 264 Shapes, that are all pointed to the same Graphics instance. This means the same 264 vector lines are drawn over top of each other 264 times. EaselJS is having to draw 264*264=69696 line segments. These repeated drawing also gives the appearance that there is no antialiasing.

Comment: Logic issue, of course. @gskinner : And a complete explanation. Thanks to both of you. CreateJS is a really nice package.