# Animation lagging after sometime - Easeljs caching

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

The animation works alright on load but after sometime it's lagging. I was creating new `drops` variables inside the for loop at first. Making it global didn't help. `fps` is 40 with 5 `particles`. Any help?

```
function init(){
  stage = new createjs.Stage("rain-canvas");
  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(fps);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", refresh);
}

function refresh(){
  for(var i = 0; i < particles; i++){
    drops = new createjs.Shape();
    xxx = Math.random() * viewportWidth;
    yyy = -10 + Math.random() * 10;
    drops.graphics.beginFill('#fff').rect(xxx, yyy, 2, 18);
    drops.alpha = 0.15 + Math.random() * 0.5;
    stage.addChild(drops);

    TweenLite.to(drops, 1.25, {y: viewportHeight + 150,
      onComplete: function(){
        stage.removeChild(drops);
      }, ease: Power1.easeNone
    });
  };
  stage.update();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@derz answer is sufficient, but I wanted to make a suggestion.

Particles should almost definitely not be shapes. Shapes get really expensive to render after you have a few hundred. Caching can make a huge difference, and in your case, you only have one shape, although you draw its x/y differently every time.

To simplify this:

1. Draw the shape once (at 0,0) and cache it
2. Use bitmaps instead, and point to the cached shape
3. Set the x/y directly each time

Here is a quick sample: http://jsfiddle.net/r0f04fvt/

**Caching A Shape**

```
var template = new createjs.Shape();
template.graphics.beginFill('#fff').rect(0, 0, 2, 18);
template.cache(0,0,2,18); // Cache it

var drops = new createjs.Bitmap(template cacheCanvas);
```

One additional thing you can do, which is common in particle engines is to pool your particles, rather than constantly destroying/creating them. Look into Object Pooling for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Check the answer over here: [EaselJS with 200+ vector shapes : performance and aesthetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215208/easeljs-with-200-vector-shapes-performance-and-aesthetics/28238446#28238446)

You shouldn't create a new `Shape` in every frame. Instead do it once and save it somehwere and add it to the stage. Afterwards you can just update the graphics command. If you need further help feel free to post a working  example (on jsfiddle) and I'll update it accordingly.